# Hadoop Map task/Map object

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

As per theory following properties are to define number of map/red task slots at data node.
`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum | mapred.map.tasks`.

Also, number of mapper objects is decided by the number of input splits in the MapReduce job. We implement map/red function and framework creates objects and sends them closest to data blocks.

So what is the difference between map task slots and mapper objects created by framework.

Lets say i am storing 2TB file across 5 data nodes, each node having 400Mb.
If i define `dfs.block.size =100Mb` then each node will hold 400/100 = 4 data blocks. Here, out of 4 data blocks we can ideally have 4 input splits and in turn 4 mapper objects per node. And at the same time if i define `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum = 2` & `mapred.map.tasks=2`, then what conclusion can i make out of it. Can i say 4 mapper objects are to be shared among 2 map task slots. I might be going in a wrong direction, any clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `map slots` determine how many `map tasks` the tasktrackers can run. The `map tasks` is determined by input splits and you can't change it. If the `map tasks` more than `map slots` some `map tasks` will block and run until other tasks has finished.

Comment: thank you for clarifying.so technically what is the difference between map slots and map tasks. can i say map tasks are nothing but multiple jvms( to run multiple mapper objects). And what is SLOT then ?

Comment: Hadoop user `slot` to divide computer resources. Computer resources include memory and cpu.